# How do I change the caption for a figure in Latex?

Tags: latex, formatting

I would like to change the caption from being:

Figure 1: ...

to

From left to right: ...

If I try and renewcommand the figurename, they still get numbered. This is unecessary as there is only a single image in the document.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could also use the `caption` package to remove the "Figure 1:" from the `\caption{}` command.

```
\usepackage{caption}
...
\begin{figure}
\caption*{A figure}
. . .
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Can you give an example? Do you provide any parameters, or just include the package?

Answer (score 7):

If you *want* to use `\caption{...}` to specify the caption, you can use this hack in your document:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil#2\hfil}%
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother
```

With this instruction, your figures will display only what you have specified as `\caption{...}` and won't add any "Figure 1: " etc.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `\caption` you may consider putting your own content beneath the figure's content:

```
\includegraphics{...}

\small
From left to right: ...
```

Answer (score 4):

[Geoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765821/how-do-i-change-the-caption-for-a-figure-in-latex/2765838#2765838) is basically correct. Within a `figure` or `table` environment, you can drop the caption if you don't want numbering, and just write plain text. From the book [A Guide to LaTeX, 3rd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201398257) (p.184):

> The \caption command may be omitted if numbering is unwanted, since any text included in the *float* environment will accompany the contents. The advantages of \caption over simple text are the automatic numbering and entries in the lists of figures and tables.